# How to remove duplicates based on condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my sample table:

| idmain | idtime | idperson1 | idperson2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 141 | 20220106 | 510 | 384 |
| 221 | 20220107 | 300 | 184 |
| 221 | 20220107 | 301 | 184 |
| 465 | 20220108 | 300 | 184 |
| 525 | 20220109 | 111 | 123 |
| 525 | 20220109 | 112 | 123 |
| 525 | 20220109 | 113 | 123 |

Duplicated records only differ by `idperson1`. So I require to remove these records preserving only the record with the max value of `idperson1`. So my final table should be:

| idmain | idtime | idperson1 | idperson2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 141 | 20220106 | 510 | 384 |
| 221 | 20220107 | 301 | 184 |
| 465 | 20220108 | 300 | 184 |
| 525 | 20220109 | 113 | 123 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4c2b232bafcd68fb1525bf13c6367bb5)

Comment: The query to gives the required result is just a simple `GROUP BY` query.

Comment: Explain what logic you use to choose "idperson1" for inclusion. I suspect the MAX aggregate is not appropriate based on the name but that does seem to be your approach. Is it logically valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you can use subquery to obtain max value of idperson1.
then use this condition like this:

```
select a.* from fact1 a
where idperson1=(select max(b.idperson1) from fact1 b where a.idtime=b.idtime and a.idperson2=b.idperson2);
```